# Java no UI update after Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, frame, windowbuilder

So, I have got this problem in my Java Swing project where I am making a bot that automatically runs through a whileloop and outputs a text that the user can define in a textfield.

Here you can see my code for adding a textline into a jlabel into my frame:

```
btnAddTalking = new JButton("Add");
    btnAddTalking.setBounds(144, 211, 146, 23);
    btnAddTalking.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(!txtTalk.getText().equals("")) {


            JLabel newLabel = new JLabel(txtTalk.getText());
            newLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                    frame.remove(newLabel);
                    frame.repaint();

                }
            });             

            newLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            newLabel.setBounds(159, yLabel, 101, 20);

            frame.getContentPane().add(newLabel);

            yLabel = yLabel + 20;

            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            frame.repaint();
            Talk.addTalk(txtTalk.getText());

        }
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddTalking);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblDelayInMs);
```

After that I start my bot by pressing the following button:

```
btnStartTalking = new JButton("Start AutoTalk");
    btnStartTalking.setBounds(144, 143, 146, 23);
    btnStartTalking.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            int robotDelay = Integer.parseInt(timeTalk.getText());

            Talk.action = "start"; 

            robotTalk = txtTalk.getText();

            if (rdbtnRed.isSelected() == true) {

                robotTalk = "red:" + txtTalk.getText();

            } else if (rdbtnFlash.isSelected() == true) {

                robotTalk = "flash1:" + txtTalk.getText();

            } else if (rdbtnGlow.isSelected() == true) {

                robotTalk = "glow1:" + txtTalk.getText();

            } 

            autoTalkStart = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        btnStartTalking.setEnabled(false);
                        btnStopTalking.setEnabled(true);
                        btnAddTalking.setEnabled(false);
                        Talk test = new Talk(robotDelay);
                    } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(autoTalkStart).start();




        }
    });
```

Via that button I start a thread which runs through a code that outputs the string. But after I've runned that Thread, my frame doesn't show newly-added jlabels anymore that you've added by clicking the btnAddTalking-button after you've run the Thread by clicking on the btnStartTalking-button! So, my question is: does anyone now how that's even possible (why my UI doesn't update anymore after i've run the thread)?

Greetz,

Jarnov

Here you can see my whole code for the two classes (class 1):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import com.sun.glass.ui.Robot;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class AutoTalker {

private static JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtTalk;
private JTextField timeTalk;
public String robotTalk;
private JButton btnStopTalking;
private JButton btnAddTalking;
private JButton btnStartTalking;
private int yLabel = 266;
private Runnable autoTalkStart;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */


public static void NewFrame() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AutoTalker window = new AutoTalker();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 * @return 
 */


public AutoTalker() {
    initialize();
}




/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize()  {



    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 415);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("AutoTalker");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    JRadioButton rdbtnGlow = new JRadioButton("Glow");
    rdbtnGlow.setBounds(6, 113, 64, 23);
    rdbtnGlow.setActionCommand("glow");
    frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnGlow);


    JRadioButton rdbtnFlash = new JRadioButton("Flash");
    rdbtnFlash.setBounds(182, 113, 69, 23);
    rdbtnGlow.setActionCommand("flash");
    frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnFlash);


    JRadioButton rdbtnRed = new JRadioButton("Red");
    rdbtnRed.setBounds(364, 113, 64, 23);
    rdbtnGlow.setActionCommand("red");
    frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnRed);


    final ButtonGroup rdbtnPressed = new ButtonGroup();
    rdbtnPressed.add(rdbtnRed);
    rdbtnPressed.add(rdbtnFlash);
    rdbtnPressed.add(rdbtnGlow);

    txtTalk = new JTextField();
    txtTalk.setBounds(130, 28, 173, 20);
    txtTalk.setColumns(10);

    btnStopTalking = new JButton("Stop AutoTalk");
    btnStopTalking.setBounds(144, 177, 146, 23);
    btnStopTalking.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Talk.action = "stop";
            btnStartTalking.setEnabled(true);
            btnStopTalking.setEnabled(false);
            btnAddTalking.setEnabled(true);
            frame.repaint();

        }
    });





    btnStartTalking = new JButton("Start AutoTalk");
    btnStartTalking.setBounds(144, 143, 146, 23);
    btnStartTalking.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            int robotDelay = Integer.parseInt(timeTalk.getText());

            Talk.action = "start"; 

            robotTalk = txtTalk.getText();

            if (rdbtnRed.isSelected() == true) {

                robotTalk = "red:" + txtTalk.getText();

            } else if (rdbtnFlash.isSelected() == true) {

                robotTalk = "flash1:" + txtTalk.getText();

            } else if (rdbtnGlow.isSelected() == true) {

                robotTalk = "glow1:" + txtTalk.getText();

            } 

            autoTalkStart = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        btnStartTalking.setEnabled(false);
                        btnStopTalking.setEnabled(true);
                        btnAddTalking.setEnabled(false);
                        Talk test = new Talk(robotDelay);
                    } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(autoTalkStart).start();
            frame.repaint();




        }
    });

    timeTalk = new JTextField();
    timeTalk.setBounds(174, 71, 86, 20);
    timeTalk.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Text:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(24, 28, 46, 20);

    JLabel lblDelayInMs = new JLabel("Delay in ms:");
    lblDelayInMs.setBounds(24, 71, 101, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtTalk);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnStartTalking);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnStopTalking);
    frame.getContentPane().add(timeTalk);

    btnAddTalking = new JButton("Add");
    btnAddTalking.setBounds(144, 211, 146, 23);
    btnAddTalking.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(!txtTalk.getText().equals("")) {

            JLabel newLabel = new JLabel(txtTalk.getText());
            newLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                    frame.remove(newLabel);
                    frame.repaint();

                }
            });             

            newLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            newLabel.setBounds(159, yLabel, 101, 20);

            frame.getContentPane().add(newLabel);

            yLabel = yLabel + 20;

            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            frame.repaint();
            Talk.addTalk(txtTalk.getText());

        }
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddTalking);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblDelayInMs);
    btnStopTalking.setEnabled(false);








}
}
```

class 2:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Talk extends AutoTalker {

Robot robot = new Robot();
public static String action;
public static ArrayList<String> Talks = new ArrayList<String>();

public Talk(int wait) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {     

robot.delay(5000);
while(action == "start") {  
for(int i = 0; i < Talks.size();i++) {  


String text = Talks.get(i);



    type(text);
    robot.delay(wait);  



}
}




}  

public static void addTalk(String text) {

Talks.add(text);

}


private void type(String s)

{
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

        char c = s.charAt(i);  
switch(c) {

case '!':
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1); 



 break;  
 case ':':
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);   





 break;
 default:           

robot.keyPress(Character.toUpperCase(c));


break; 




}
robot.delay(10);

}

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);  
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.delay(10);


}



}
```

Comment: You mention JavaFX in your question text, but this is not JavaFX code.  Also, use of `com.sun.glass` classes is not advised as they are not part of the publicly exported JRE API and their interface may change or be removed in future Java versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought that it was JavaFX code, but I might be wrong :). Do you know what i'm actually doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Swing development, so I will retain from answering this.  I edited your question to remove the JavaFX reference and add a Swing tag, which might help you pick up some Swing experts willing to look at it.  Rather than dumping your whole code, you might get a better chance of responses if you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note that must be both *minimal* and *complete*, in that it can be compiled and executed to run).  Also, format the code with correct indentation and removal of useless whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use instead

```
invalidate();
validate();
```